# App Engine, can't operate on multiple entity groups in a single transaction

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I receive the following exception when I try to update multiple objects in one transaction:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't operate on multiple entity groups in a single transaction.found both Element {
  type: "Message"
  id: 51
}
 and Element {
  type: "Message"
  id: 52
}

This is strange because all of the objects in the transaction share a common ancestor.

When I print the list I receive the following:

[
SITE ID:2 MESSAGE ID:50 MESSAGE CREATED BY:north@gmail.com CREATED ON:Fri May 04 05:38:32 UTC 2012, 
SITE ID:2 MESSAGE ID:51 MESSAGE CREATED BY:north@gmail.com CREATED ON:Fri May 04 05:38:32 UTC 2012, 
SITE ID:2 MESSAGE ID:52 MESSAGE CREATED BY:north@gmail.com CREATED ON:Fri May 04 05:38:32 UTC 2012
]

As you can see, all three message records lookup to the same parent site with id of 2.  According to the [GAE documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions) this means the messages are in the same entity group so it seems that I shouldn't be getting this exception.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We can't really help without seeing some source code. Can you include a simplest possible example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Additional to the request of @Nick above, the most likely explanation is that your two `Message` persistent entities (of IDs 51 and 52) are indeed in separate entity groups.

Comment: Nick and Ian, thank you for your responses.  Before I put in the work to distill my code for a post here, could you explain how entities are saved within the same group?  My understanding was that if they both lookup to another object then they are part of the same entity group.  In my case, "lookup" means that a Message object has a persistent field, Long siteId, which I set on insert.

Comment: I'm using python and I ran into the same problem. I think you have to make the group's connection explicit (using ancestor queries to retrieve objects or building it with parent specified). Using straight reference doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error when try to update more that one item. Work around - I moved it to different transactions. Think it is not possible to update more that one item in single transaction.

Comment: The other workaround is to do the following: [1] Add this property to your jdoconfig.xml file,  property 'name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>', and [2] edit you run configuration to enable High Replication Datastore, go Run> Run Configurations> App Engine> HRD Configuration> check "Enable Local HRD Support."  I haven't had a chance to look into the full implications of enabling HRD.

Comment: Correction, the property should be:  <property name="datanucleus.appengine.datastoreEnableXGTransactions" value="true"/>

Comment: Added this property to persistence.xml, HDR was enabled by default. But this doesn't solve issue :(